# Aborting thread + socket connection

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, dispose

I have a (very basic understandig, as i think) question on threading and aborting these:

Situation is: I have an open socket connection in a thread working - now I am aborting the thread by `thread.Abort()`.

Question is: what happens to the socket connection? Will it be closed and disposed? Or do I have to take care of this by myself?

Appendix:

Threads are created here:

```
foreach (Pcd pcd in LstPcds)
        {
           Thread.Sleep(delay);
           Thread thread = new Thread(pcd.Simulate);
           _lstActiveThreads.Add(thread);
           thread.IsBackground = true;
           thread.Name = pcd.ToString();
           thread.Start();
           count++;
        }
```

and should be disposed/aborted/whatever here:

```
  public void DisposePcds()
  {
     try
     {
        foreach (Thread thread in _lstActiveThreads)
        {
           thread.Abort();
        }
     }
     catch (Exception exception)
     {
        MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
     }
  }
```

Each `thread` has an open `Socket` connection as shown here:

```
// connecting (async) to the service
// blocks the thread until connection is established
ConnectionSocket = new Socket(_ipEndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
ConnectionSocket.BeginConnect(_ipEndPoint, ConnectCallback, ConnectionSocket);
_manualConnectEvent.WaitOne();

// begin receive data from the server
ReceiveDto receive = new ReceiveDto { Socket = ConnectionSocket };
ConnectionSocket.BeginReceive(receive.Buffer, 0, ReceiveDto.GetBufferSize(), 0, ReceiveCallback, receive);
```

plus a Timer and its elapsed event where each `Socket` sends a byte array:

```
byte[] request = GetRegisterRequestCommand(bank);
ConnectionSocket.Send(request, SocketFlags.None);
```

Comment: Never use `Thread.Abort()`. Really. There is rarely ever a valid reason to use it. You should use a mechanism (such as `AutoResetEvent`, etc.) to allow threads to shut themselves down properly.

Comment: Could you show us the part, where you abort the thread and close the connection?

Comment: Socket connection will not be closed automatically. You have to do it manually. Showing the code helps for us to be sure :)

Comment: code snippets added, hope this helps a bit (thx for this early morning support)

Comment: It is not clear where your threads created? What your threads were doing at the time of abortion? It seems you're using Async API of socket. There is no good reason to use threads and I don't see that too. Where do you create your threads and what does it does?

Comment: `Thread.Abort` is unpredictable and should be avoided for *manageable* situations like this. Look at how you can perform [Task Cancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx) using the TPL.

Comment: @James I disagree. `Thread.Abort` should be very predictable. What you don't have is control. I don't even think you can catch `ThreadAbortException`. Which means you CAN'T even try to clean up.

Comment: As @SriramSakthivel is saying. You don't NEED threading. You can do this all single-threaded asynchronously. [Please read Stephen Cleary's post on the subject](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Comment: @Aron by the *unpredictable* part I was referring to the code running inside the thread after it's been aborted - like you say you have no control. It's best to implement a more manageable solution, especially when you do need to clean up stuff.

Comment: @Aron that's debatable, using the `async`/`await` construct will still have to wait *eventually*. For long running tasks or I/O intensive tasks it's still recommended you use threading.

Comment: @James waiting isn't a bad thing. BLOCKING is the problem. `await` produces non-blocking waits. The issue with blocking is that threads are really really expensive. 8mb of ram + scheduling.

Comment: @Aron Small correction not 8mb it is 1mb. Correct me if am wrong :)

Comment: @Aron threads are only expensive if you are spinning them up - leveraging the TPL and re-using threads is less intensive.

Comment: @James They are expensive due to memory usage and context switching. When you have more threads than processors, you invariable need to context switch to give each thread scheduling time. But the major cost comes from threads, sleeping and awaking. You still want to minimalism the number of threads. However, you wouldn't be able to reuse your thread if you abort it.

Comment: @James if you aren't efficient with your threads, then even ThreadPool threads won't be enough. My point is that you should keep each thread unblocked. Especially your UI thread.

Comment: @Aron leveraging the TPL is more efficient that spinning up new threads, however, that of course doesn't mean that you can't exhaust the usage of that thread by code. We are on the same page, I was just pointing out that threading/async both have their uses - and without really knowing what the OP is using threads for in this instance you can't be sure enough to state that they didn't need to use threading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the MSDN documentation on the subject.

Firstly. NO your code could never ever work. Disposables need to be either explicitly call `.Dispose()` on them OR they are called implicitly via the syntactical sugar of `using(IDisposable){}`.

Now looking at the `ThreadAbortException` you are able to catch exceptions (but it gets rethrown). So `using` (which is transformed by the compiler to `try{}finally{Dispose()}`) will work.

But you have no exception handling.

Comment: thanks aron - i know that this code won't work in any of our universes, but actually this was not a question for a "real" scenario, it just occured to me as a lack of understanding of how "disposing" threads and its inner actions works.